# Setting up SendGrid with Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, sendgrid

I have a Windows Azure account and am using Azure Mobile Services with my Windows 8 Store App, and have followed the instructions in [this tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sendgrid-email-service/#reference), but there is a problem somewhere and there isn't any information about it online.

The [tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sendgrid-email-service/#reference) I'm following says to Add SendGrid as a Nuget Reference to the project, but there are 2 options when you search for SendGrid (the tutorial only shows 1 option), I have tried to install both (one at a time, and only when the first one didn't work) - but both of them display the same error message.

It can't install because my Windows Store App is running .NET Framework 4.5 (which is how it's supposed to be), and that the SendGrid library isn't compatible with .NET Framework 4.5.

How can I send e-mails from within my Windows Store App using SendGrid? Or how do I just get SendGrid to work?

Here's how it looks on my end when I try to install either of the options:
[image: Cannot install SendGrid in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate]

The text in the image says:

> Could not install package SendGridPlus 2.1.1. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   .NETCore,Version=v4.5, but the package does not contain any assembly
>   references that are compatible with that framework. For more
>   information, contact the author.

## Updates

As suggested by @Pascal, I have used the Package Manager Console to install it, with:
Install-Package Sendgrid -Version 1.0.1

But it just threw the exact same error message at me:

> PM> Install-Package Sendgrid -Version 1.0.1 Successfully installed
>   'Sendgrid 1.0.1'. Successfully uninstalled 'Sendgrid 1.0.1'. Install
>   failed. Rolling back... Install-Package : Could not install package
>   'Sendgrid 1.0.1'. You are trying to install this  package into a
>   project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not
>   contain  any assembly references that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact  the package author. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Sendgrid -Version 1.0.1
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallP
>   ackageCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to install the Sendgrid package version 1.0.1 (as stated in the tutorial) using the Package Manager Console instead of the NuGet GUI.

```
Install-Package Sendgrid -Version 1.0.1
```

The latest version of the Sengrid package is version 1.1.1 which depends on RestSharp which unfortunately doesn't have a version targeting WinRT (.NETCore,Version=v4.5).

-Edit: The SendGrid package cannot be used in Windows Store Apps.  For an Azure Mobile Service  SendGrid should be used directly in a script on the Azure Portal

Comment: Did not work: I am updating my question to include the error as it's a bit too long for comment box.

Comment: that tutorial does _not_ tell you to use the Package Manager Console to install SendGrid. It even has an image - almost as big as the screen - showing you that they want you to install it using the References > Add Nuget Preference > Online > SendGrid > Install method.

Comment: Hmm... just noticed what's wrong... for Mobile Services you should use this tutorial: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/send-email-with-sendgrid/.  The tutorial you were following is for a normal .NET application (or Web/Worker role in Azure)

Comment: Really? @Pascal, that's strange. I  did not know it was for a normal application, because the screenshots in it were of Metro style apps, and I got to that page because a link on the Azure site said it was a tut for Windows Store Apps

Comment: thanks for the link, checking it out now. I did try installing the latest version of Nuget, though with no luck. Still the errors.

Comment: So with the link you just gave me, @Pascal, there's no need to add anything to my code in VS. It's all done from within Script editor in Management Portal, am I correct? Thanks by the way :)

Comment: Yes exactly.  Also I don't see any screenshots of a Windows Store Apps in the How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Windows Azure tutorial.  Only of the Azure Portal and SendGrid management web site.

Comment: Sigh, I wish things were a lot simpler sometimes. Thanks for helping @Pascal :-) I'm pretty sure I've got everything I need now to get this working :)

Comment: thanks so much man. I got this working - I can now send e-mails, yippee!

Answer (score 1):

Try updating nuget to the latest version if you don't already have that before doing the install.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mobile Services, the best way to work with SendGrid is to add it to your WA subscription through the Store and then trigger the email based on a designated CRUD op on one of your tables.  Here's a tutorial specific to SendGrid and Mobile Services that also includes adding SendGrid from the Store: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/send-email-with-sendgrid/